# NGINX not protecting directory

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I managed to setup a .htaccess for this once in the past and can't seem to replicate.

I'm trying to protect the domain that a laravel project resides in (/home/forge/default/)

I have my .htaccess and .htpasswd files in the /home/forge/ directory.

My NGINX settings:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
auth_basic            "Basic";
auth_basic_user_file  /home/forge/.htpasswd;
}
```

My .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/forge/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

htpasswd contains a username//password: dev:passwordhashhere, and the .htpasswd has the proper permissions.

It seems that nothing happens when accessing the app via the browser (page loads without the prompt for username/password). I'm guessing it has something to do with my NGINX settings. Any ideas?

EDIT: Worth noting that I am using Laravel Forge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

```
server_name domain.tld;
...

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /log {
autoindex on;
auth_basic "Restricted Access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/domain.tld/.htpasswd.domain.tld
}
...
```

i have not a .htaccess, only htpasswd with :

```
user:$arr$sdv56sd31v3dv ......
```

when i go to:

```
http://domain.tld/log
```

authentification is required.

Please , clear your cache's browser before you try to login into webrowser.
If you want see more informations , in your browser , search network informations for request observation.

And finally , your post is not on the good place , for server configuration it's serverfault or superuser not stack (programming).Correct me if I'm wrong.